# getTransactionCount always returns 1048576, no matter what address

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, testnets, nonce, morden

No matter what random address I use, `web3.eth.getTransactionCount` always prints **1048576**

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0xb222a0f8f77dbbc3a0fc87f77717ddc59cf225d7")

1048576
```

Let say, I change a simple character in the address (the last character from 7 to 8)

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0xb222a0f8f77dbbc3a0fc87f77717ddc59cf225d8")

1048576
```

Shouldn't it display 0? Interestingly, the number 1048576 is 0x100000 in hexadecimal.

Perhaps I'm doing something very stupidly wrong... but I can't get behind it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are on a testnet, which implements an initial `nonce` of 2^20 = 0x100000 = 1048576

More details here:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Morden#details

> Initial Account Nonce (IAN) is 2^20 (instead of 0 in all previous networks).

By setting an initial `nonce` higher than it could possibly reach on the main Ethereum network, they prevent testnet transactions from being valid on the live network (preventing replay attacks).